# (Laravel) errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql, laravel

I wanna create `chapter` table and `lessons` table, the `chapter` table created on database but `lesson` table doesn't exist with an error message like

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
> `ecomm_product`.`#sql-2138_1a` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
> incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `chapters` add constraint
> `chapters_course_id_foreign` foreign key (`course_id`) references
> `courses` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Here's my `chapters` table schema:

```
Schema::create('chapters', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->foreignId('course_id')->constrained('courses')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and, here's my `lessons` table schema:

```
Schema::create('lessons', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('video');
    $table->foreignId('chapters_id')->constrained('chapters')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Anyone please help me with this problem, thank you.

Comment: The error refers to a problem with a foreign key referencing the `courses` table, but you haven't posted the definition of that table.

Comment: my bad, here's the courses schema https://pastebin.com/eET1PCqJ

Answer (score 0):

Add foreign key as below:

```
$table->foreign('chapters_id')->references('id')->on('chapters')->onDelete('cascade');
```